# Take ownership, add column value and check in - powershell

Tags: powershell, metadata

We have some files that have been dragged into a library via explorer view. Before doing so, someone forgot to set a column to not be mandatory. Because of this they are checked out with no previous version. There are 10k of these docs!

What I need to do is to take ownership of the docs.

I have tried `$Item.File.TakeOverCheckIn('Checked in by admin')`

But either nothing happens or I get a message saying that SPFile does not have a method called `TakeOverCheckIn`

I have Googled and this is where I saw PS examples quoting TakeOverCheckIn()

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved it, I needed to iterate through CheckedOutFiles rather than Items.
Here is the code that did it for me, took over check out and then checked them in

```
ForEach($item in $doclib.checkedoutfiles){ 
    $item.TakeoverCheckout()
    $doclib.GetItemById($item.ListItemId).file.CheckIn("Checked in by Admin") 
    #write-host "$($item.LeafName) has been checked in" 
}
```